# 'outchar', 'outint', but not 'outfloat'

Tags: c, type-mismatch

I'm learning C because I have a book though it is as old as I am. I am using turboc++ and it works when I return 0; at the end of functions but I'm led to believe this was not always necessary. I am going through the exercises on functions. 
outfloat will give me type mismatch in re-declaration of outfloat but the others work. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{
    outchar('A');
    outnum(2);
    outfloat(3.3);
    return 0;
}


outchar(char ch)
{
    printf("%c",ch);
    return 0;
}
outnum(int x)
{
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
outfloat(float z)
{
    printf("%f",z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf(%f",z);`is wrong. You are missing `"` character for beginning

Comment: I added the " , doesn't change the problem

Comment: That's no valid C, nor C++! Get a more recent toolchain! TurboC is outdated since 24 years! Don't you think C has developed since then?

Comment: You didn't specify the return type of your functions, so they're expected to return `int` (if you're not getting an error).  If you specify a `void` return type, you won't need the return statement.

Comment: @Dmitri: "so they're expected to return int" - No. C requires a return type since 18 years.

Comment: @Olaf If he's not using a compiler that supports it, he'd probably get an error.

Comment: @Dmitri Your conclusing is wrong. OP should **definitively** remove TC from his harddrive, get a more recent C book and a modern toolchain (gcc or clang are the best picks for a beginner) , not try to fix code which is broken by design.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not suggesting he *should* omit return types, but since he did, his compiler probably assumed a return of `int`.

Comment: To be clear this code was written to illustrate a problem I was having doing one of the exercises. the book only lists outchar (copied verbatim). I want to use this book because 
A: I want to learn C
B: I have this book

Comment: As for prototyping, I don't know what that means. My last experience in programming was 10 years ago in high school using java.

Comment: " I want to use this book because A: I want to learn C" - Judging from the code you **do not learn C from this book!** To be very clear: The code shown is **not** valid C since 18 years! "B: I have this book" - I might have some old VIC64 book lying around. But I don't use it to program modern hardware. That is not even a bad argument. Or do you consider a beginner learning medieval English for business negotiations   a good idea?

Comment: I consider it enlightening to learn to program C as is done 'modernly' using material that is old, and troubleshooting the differences. I figure it will make me that much more wary of future scruples, I'm doing this for 'fun'.

and your example is a false dichotomy though I am neither versed in medieval English or programming languages to elucidate as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't provide a prototype for any of the functions used, the compiler assumes their parameters (and return type) are `int`.

For the first two functions that assumption "works".

For the last function, the assumption fails because the the parameter of type `float` is not compatible with (the assumed) type `int`.

Your best bet is to **always provide prototypes for the functions you use**. In the simple code you have you can use the fact that a function definition also serves as a prototype and move the definitions to before `main()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* prototypes */
int outchar(char ch);
int outnum(int x);
int outfloat(float z);

int main(void)
{
    outchar('A');
    outnum(2);
    outfloat(3.3);
    return 0;
}

int outchar(char ch)
{
    printf("%c",ch);
    return 0;
}

int outnum(int x)
{
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}

int outfloat(float z)
{
    printf("%f",z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not know what prototyping means but before posting this I was under the suspicion that if I defined the functions before main it might work, however I didn't what to do this because it's "bad coding" though I don't know why I just know that it is.

Comment: Prototypes are used to let the compiler know about the function **before** using the function, making it possible for it to produce correct code. I see nothing wrong in defining functions before `main()`, but if you don't like that, you can use proper prototypes (not functions definitions, see updated answer).

Comment: thank you before your updated answer I just put all of the functions before main. Now I understand what a prototype is and how to make one (which will help me complete the exercise that I have code written for while still keeping main at the top with fewer changes. (I'm doing the writing in notepad++ so its not a big deal but this looks "prettier"). 

I do have a question that may be out of scope but, since I have you,  why are all the functions and prototypes defined with int to begin with (when they aren't necessarily integers) and what other keywords could be used and with what purpose?

Comment: @radzvi: "however I didn't what to do this because it's "bad coding" though I don't know why I just know that it is." - Who told you this? It is plain nonsense! Actually this is normal coding style in most programming languages requiring declarations before usage..

Comment: I understand you can do "what you want" and "as long as it works" but I was under the assumption that you want your 'main' to be clean, succinct, and easy to refer to. I'm not a programmer, I don't know what I don't know which is mostly everything.

Comment: @radzvi: your original functions ended with `return 0;`. As `0` has type `int` and I didn't want to make any more changes than necessary, I used that type as the return type of the functions. Other than that, functions can return all the other C types, or return nothing at all in which case they are written as"returning" `void` (very different than `void*`), for example `void foobar(int, int);` for a function named "foobar" that accepts two parameters of type `int` and does not return a value.